# Unable to get signer I.e required for completing transactions

Tags: gnosis-safe

We are integrating gnosis safe wallet into our app with ethers library but we are unable to get signer i.e requried for completing transactions. Can someone from team help me

Comment: could you please describe your issue in detail?

Comment: A contract cannot sign a transaction. In this case gnosis is a multisig contract.